# Multiple Condition inside php array

Tags: php, arrays, filter, conditional-statements

How do I check the minimum value inside php array with multiple condition. My array is below:

```
$arr = [[472 =>['EL' => 52.9,'MT' => 57.375 'MO' => 56.6,'SC' => 26,'ET' => 50.775]], 
       [505 =>['EL' => 53.425,'MT' => 25,'MO' => 62.8,'SC' => 23,'ET' => 25]]];    
$total = array_reduce(
   $arr,
   function($arr, $key) {
     $id = key($key);
     $consumed = $key[$id];
     $sc = array_keys($consumed);
     $arr[$id] = [
       "totalc" => array_sum($consumed),
       "condition" =>  array_search('SC', $sc) ? min($consumed) >= 23:min($consumed) >=26
     ];
     return $arr;
   },
   []
 );
```

If the key is 'SC', the minimum value for 'SC' is 23, But for the value of other key the minimum value is 26. So the above code must produce the following output:

```
 Array
(
    [472] => Array
        (
            [totalc] => 243.65
            [condition] => 1
        )    
    [505] => Array
        (
            [totalc] => 189.225
            [condition] => 
        )
    )
```

The `SC` key in both the array ( [472] and [505] ) meet the minimum condition 23 but the value of the key `ET` does not meet the minimum condition 26. So the array [505] should produce `false` on the value of `condition` key. But if we change the value of `ET` to 26 or more on the [505] array, we still get `false` value. But the correct value must be `1` or `true`. So if the array is like below:

```
$arr = [[472 =>['EL' => 52.9,'MT' => 57.375 'MO' => 56.6,'SC' => 26,'ET' => 50.775]], 
           [505 =>['EL' => 53.425,'MT' => 25,'MO' => 62.8,'SC' => 23,'ET' => 26]]];
```

The correct output would be :

```
Array
    (
        [472] => Array
            (
                [totalc] => 243.65
                [condition] => 1
            )    
        [505] => Array
            (
                [totalc] => 189.225
                [condition] => 1
            )
        )
```

In short, the min value of 'SC' should be 23 and the mim value of other KEYS(EL, MT,MO,ET) should be 26. I tried to solve this problem for almost two days and two nights, it still does not work. So if you could help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I showed the expected output. Look at carefully, the sample array are not the same on the key ET value.

Comment: in 505 array MT has value 'MT' => 25 so condition should be false right? or just value of ET and SC has to check

Comment: Yes. Correct. The problem is : it is not true when it is 26 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [[472 => ['EL' => 52.9, 'MT' => 57.375, 'MO' => 56.6, 'SC' => 26, 'ET' => 50.775]],
        [505 => ['EL' => 53.425, 'MT' => 25, 'MO' => 62.8, 'SC' => 23, 'ET' => 26]]];
function pr($arr)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$total = array_reduce($arr, function ($arr, $key) {
    $id   = key($key);
    $temp = $consumed = $key[$id];
    $sc   = array_keys($consumed);
    $condition = false;
    if (array_search('SC', $sc) && ($consumed['SC']) >= 23) {
        $condition = true;
    }
    unset($temp['SC']);

    $condition = ($condition && min($temp) >= 26 ? true : false);
    $arr[$id] = [
        "totalc"    => array_sum($consumed),
        "condition" => $condition,
    ];
    return $arr;
});

pr($total);die;
```

if min SC is 23 and min of all other is 26 then condition is true.

Explanation:

472 => SC = 26(>=23) and all other values are >= 26 so `condition = true`
505 => SC = 23(>=23) and now I will check other values. Now MT = 25 so `condition = false`

Lets take some sample demo examples,

```
$arr = [[472 => ['EL' => 52.9, 'MT' => 57.375, 'MO' => 56.6, 'SC' => 22, 'ET' => 50.775]],
        [505 => ['EL' => 53.425, 'MT' => 26, 'MO' => 62.8, 'SC' => 23, 'ET' => 26]]];
```

472 => SC < 23 so `condition = false` regardless of other value.
505 => SC >= 23 so `condition = true` at first, now we will check for all other values. As we saw all other are greater than 26, so `condition =true`.

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6dbe1018fe952ebb0d035546440aa18e5424d5a1)

Comment: Still not work. Both condition must be true because ET is 26 in the second array.

Comment: Since you overwrite the condition, your code does not simply work.

Comment: if min SC is 23 and min of ET is 26 then condition is true. is it? Are you trying to say SC >= 23 and ET >= 26 then true, rest all values doesn't matter?

Comment: Not only ET, for other value of KEY like EL, MT, MO, min value is 26. Just for SC min value is 23. So if SC does not meet 23, the condition must be false regardless of other value. And if any one of the value of other falls under 26, the condition must be false regardless of SC value becoming true.

Comment: Whatever criteria you explained, my snippet is working fine. Please check carefully.

Comment: You are right I overlook the MT which has a value of 25. Thanks for the help. How can I add more parameter to condition, for array_sum($consumed), I want to use other array which has the same structure as $consumed. Do you think it is possible?